# Getting an error with qt creator when compiling: "cannot find -lGL"

Tags: qt, compilation, qt-creator

I'm getting this error when trying to compile whit qt creator:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

Comment: you need to get the opengl dll / header files

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406369/qt-cant-find-lgl-error , it seems to be a frequently asked question in Ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt in Debian, can't compile, error: cannot find -lGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092733/qt-in-debian-cant-compile-error-cannot-find-lgl)

Comment: Do you have an x32 or x64 system ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following command

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```